# How do I transform the coordinates of an object in a fabricjs group to the screen coordinates

Tags: fabricjs

I have a group containing multiple rectangles. I want to highlight each rectangle in the group as the mouse hovers over it.

I have tried setting subTargetCheck to true but this does not work.

So I have managed to trap the mousemove event on the canvas and can get the group items individually, but the coordinates are somehow relative to the centre of the group which appears to be the dead center of itself. So for example if my group is 500 wide and 500 high then the center is recorded as [0,0] and the top left of the group would be [-250, -250].

How can I transform [-250, -250] (or any internal group item coordinate) into screen coordinates to do collision detection with the mouse?

```js
fabric.PoolParticipant = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Group, {
    type: 'PoolParticipant',
    hover(pointer){
        let ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d")
        ctx.font = 'caption'
        let centrePoint = this.calcTransformMatrix()
        ctx.clearRect(centrePoint[4] - 50, centrePoint[5] -40, 200, 50)
        ctx.strokeText(`${pointer.x},${pointer.y}`, centrePoint[4], centrePoint[5])

        this._objects.filter(o => o.type === ("LaneParticipant")).forEach( lane=> {
            let [ a, b, c, d, ...centrePoint ] = lane.calcTransformMatrix()
            let tl = [Math.round((centrePoint[0] - lane.width/2)), Math.round((centrePoint[1] - lane.height/2))]
            let hoverRect = [...tl, lane.width, lane.height]
            ctx.clearRect(hoverRect[0] + 40, hoverRect[1] + 25, 320, 76)
            ctx.strokeText(String(hoverRect), hoverRect[0] + 50, hoverRect[1] + 50)
            
            if(pointInRect( pointer, hoverRect ) ){
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
                ctx.strokeRect( hoverRect[0], hoverRect[1], hoverRect[2], hoverRect[3] )
                ctx.strokeText(String(lane.id), hoverRect[0] + 50, hoverRect[1] + 100)
            }
        })
    },
    initialize: function( options ) {
        
        options || (options = {});
        options.hoverCursor = 'pointer';
        options.lockRotation = true;
        options.lockScalingX = false;
        options.lockScalingY = false;
        options.hasControls = true;
        options.subTargetCheck = true;
        options.perPixelTargetFind = true;

        this.callSuper('initialize', [], options, true);
        this.set({ 'id': options.id,
                    'name': options.name,
                    "origin" : this.toLocalPoint(this.getCenterPoint(),'left', 'top')
        });
        
        this.background = new fabric.Rect({
            width: options.width,
            height: options.height,
            fill: 'white',
            type: 'Boundary',
            stroke: 'rgba(100,200,200,1)',
            strokeWidth: 2
        })

        this.labelRect = new fabric.Rect({
            width: 30,
            height: options.height - 1,
            top: 1,
            left: 1,
            fill: 'rgba(100,200,200,1)',
            stroke: 'rgba(100,200,200,1)',
            strokeWidth: 1
        })

        this.label = new fabric.Text(options.label, 
        { 
            left: 1, 
            top: options.height -1, 
            angle: -90,
            fill: "white",
            fontSize: 20
        })

        const labelTopAndBottomMargins = (options.height - this.label.getBoundingRect().height) / 2
        const labelLeftAndRightMargins = ((30 - this.label.getBoundingRect().width) / 2) + 1
        
        this.label.top = options.height - labelTopAndBottomMargins
        this.label.left = labelLeftAndRightMargins

        this.addWithUpdate(this.background)
        this.addWithUpdate(this.labelRect)

        let top = 0
        options.lanes.forEach(lane=>{
            let newLane = new fabric.LaneParticipant( { id: lane.id, label: lane.label, height: lane.height, left: 30, top: top, width: options.width - 30 } )
            this.addWithUpdate( newLane )
            top += lane.height
        })

        this.addWithUpdate(this.label)
        
    },
    toObject: function() {

        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
            id: this.get('id'),
            name: this.get('name'),
            options: this.get('options')
        });

    },
    render: function(ctx) {
      
        this.callSuper('render', ctx);

    }
})
```

Comment: "I have tried setting subTargetCheck to true but this does not work." - can you share your code that highlights the problem? I think subTargetCheck is exactly what you need and is supposed to work.

Comment: Shared the code in the OP :-)

Comment: So the highlighting is done in the `hover()` method on the PoolParticipant class from what I can see. Where and how are you calling it? This snippet is missing that code.